# Is it possible to measure Sharepoint Online page load times with Splunk?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, sharepoint-online, splunk, pageload

Is it possible to measure Sharepoint Online page load times with Splunk? I know it can be done with Application Insights. But I need to know if it's possible with Splunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You could configure a splunk rest url and call it in the header of the sharepoint. So when any page is called you can pass arguments as name of the page loaded to the url. And push an event to splunk as scripted data input.